# The difference between msg.sender.balance and owner[msg.sender]

Tags: solidity, remix, balances

Hello everyone i have a code like:

```
mapping(address => uint)owner;

function show() view public returns(uint) {
    return owner[msg.sender];
    //return msg.sender.balance;
}
```

in slodity and when i return owner[msg.sender] it shows me '0: uint256: 0'
and when i return msg.sender.balance it shows me '0: uint256: 99999999999996134991'
i want to know what's the difference and what do they mean ? 
Tnx for your help .

Comment: The first one is the amount of tokens owned by `msg.sender`, and the second one is the amount of Ether owned by `msg.sender`.

Comment: @goodvibration TnQ so much ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `owner[msg.sender]` will give you the `uint` value from the `owner` map given the `address` key. Since you have not set any value, the map will return the default values which is `0` for the `uint` (alias to `uint256`) type.
- `msg.sender.balance` returns the ETH balance in wei denomination of the sender account

Comment: Tnx for your help